# Can anyone tell me how to trigger a function when the mouse is pressed and continues untill it is released in p5.js

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, p5.js, vs-web-site-project, mobilenet

I was trying to add an image using p5 and ml5 In my website where user can train there own image and get the predicted output over webcam I tried implementing it by using

```
var addImage;
var mobilenet;
mobilenet = ml5.featureExtractor('MobileNet', modelReady);
classifier = mobilenet.classification(video,videoReady);
addImage = createButton('Insert');
addImage.mousePressed(function (){
classifier.addImage('Insert');
});
```

but for every image, I need to press the mouse button to insert I just want to make it something like this

```
**On mousePress()
  function to add multiple image;
  On mouseRelease()
  stop;**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseIsPressed), this should work;

```
var addImage;
var mobilenet;
var drawImageInterval = null;
mobilenet = ml5.featureExtractor('MobileNet', modelReady);
classifier = mobilenet.classification(video,videoReady);
addImage = createButton('Insert');
addImage.mousePressed(function (){
   if(mouseIsPressed && !drawImageInterval){
     drawImageInterval = setInterval(function(){
         classifier.addImage('Insert');
      }, 1000);
  } else {
     clearInterval(drawImageInterval);
     drawImageInterval = null;
  }

});
```